# Load Balancer certificate transfer/reuse in another region

Tags: amazon-web-services, disaster-recovery, amazon-elb, aws-certificate-manager

I am implementing disaster recovery in AWS . My application is deployed in us-east-1 and now as part of disaster recovery I wanted to create same infra in another region . Now i have challenge regarding reusing https certificate of load balancer from primary region to new region(us-east-2). Can I do how? I am not able to see proper AWS docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't reuse the *exact* same ACM-issued certificate across regions.  The procedure in this case is to create an identical certificate in the additional region.